# How to add nested comments in a Django blog

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app where I have a comments section. The comments can be made by only authenticated user. I want to add the ability to add replies to comments in a nested format, but I have no idea how.

Here is are the models which are involved into the comments part:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    content = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-page', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comment_content.all()



class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comment_content', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The modelform I created:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs= {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'message',
                'cols': '30',
                'rows': '10',
            }
        )
    )
```

The way each comment is rendered:

```
{% for comment in article.get_comments %}
                <li class="comment">
                  <div class="comment-body">
                    <h3>{{ comment.user.username }}</h3>
                    <div class="meta mb-3">{{ comment.timestamp }}</div>
                    <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have used a @property to display the comments. Do I need to change the overall way the comments are rendered? Can someone help me with creating the replies?
(The reply button doesn't do anything btw. It came with the template I am working on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would want to be able to add multiple replies to a comment you need to create another model called Replies with a many-to-one relationship to the Comment model. That way each article can have multiple comments and each comment can have multiple replies. Your Replies  model will look something like this-

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='replies',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reply = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def get_replies(self):
        return self.replies.all()
```

You can render all the replies linked to a comment the same way you do it for comments.

```
{% for comment in article.get_comments %}
    <li class="comment">
    <div class="comment-body">
        <h3>{{ comment.user.username }}</h3>
        <div class="meta mb-3">{{ comment.timestamp }}</div>
        <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>

            {% for reply in comment.get_replies %}
                <li class="reply">
                <div class="reply-body">
                    <h3>{{ reply.user.username }}</h3>
                    <div class="meta mb-3">{{ reply.timestamp }}</div>
                    <p>{{ reply.reply }}</p>
                    #ToDo Create a view to add replies and hook the url to href below
                    <p><a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a></p>
                </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why is the property get_replies inside the Reply model and not in the Comment model, unlike the way the get_comments work?